# Sliding Animation and Functionality

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm looking for some suggestions to on how to approach an animation/functionality in an iPad app.

My client has tasked me with rebuilding an old app of theirs. They don't have the original code, only the app installed on a simulator on their Mac. The video below was made using the old app on a simulator.

The best way to describe what I'm trying to do is to simply show you a short clip, here: https://youtu.be/odft0pNGdvg

Basically, I need to slide the background/scene/sprite/whatever it may be, over to reveal another panel. Then move tiles over from the new panel onto the main panel. The main panel, while moved somewhat over, can also still be interacted with.

I have a good portion of the app built with SpriteKit already, this last big features alludes me though, lol. Any ideas on how to approach this? One idea I had was stacked SKViews or SKScenes, but I can't really figure that out.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about `UIKit` structures, I can see a "slide menu" where the left view have a double animation of scaling and fading. Speaking about `sprite-kit`, if you want to realize something similar to that video, you can make an `SKScene` with two `SKNode`, a couple of buttons on the top of the first `SKNode` to change its behaviour, each node should have a "background" sprite where the left node should have 55% or 60% of the full scene size width, the second node should have the full size of the scene.

The first situation will be: the left node hided and zoomed out and the right node covering the full screen with a `zPosition` greater than the left node.

Then you should implement the swiping gestures and animating the nodes following your demonstration video, so the left node should move to the right with a right swipe and in the same time left node should appear , scaling and fading to the left part of the screen. It should simple to making.